# Serving pages depending on domain name

Tags: meteor

Is it possible that several domain names redirect to the same IP (and thus Meteor app), and that this app can detect the domain name from which it is served and redirect to a specific route that would appear as the root route ?

Mickael

Comment: You can get the url using `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`, so I suppose the answer is yes

Comment: I think this is not possible without setting the right forward setings on your nginx. You then can use `HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT` (see [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#HTTP-FORWARDED-COUNT)) and check on the user's connection / user agent for the forwarded headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. All the answers are here:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/serving-pages-depending-on-domain-name/49439